# what is the difference between Redux CombineReducers and Redux-toolkit ConfigureStore

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import testSlice from "./testSlice";
import {combineReducers} from "redux";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({test: testSlice})
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});
```

Which one is better? for performance and use purpose. Which is good to use?

Comment: configureStore is more like createReducer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are totally different things.

If the `reducer` option is an object of slice reducers, like `{ users: usersReducer, posts: postsReducer }`, `configureStore` will automatically create the root reducer by passing this object to the Redux `combineReducers` utility. See [source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/6642f43d1d86ee34b853c6cc0fa121a464152e1f/packages/toolkit/src/configureStore.ts#L144)

```js
  if (typeof reducer === 'function') {
    rootReducer = reducer
  } else if (isPlainObject(reducer)) {
    rootReducer = combineReducers(reducer)
  } else {
    throw new Error(
      '"reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers'
    )
  }
```

RTK `configureStore` setup the redux store configuration, not only `reducer`, but also middlewares, dev tools, preloaded state, and enhancers.

The Redux `combineReducers` helper function turns an object whose values are different reducing functions into a single reducing function